# Matches function doesn't run

Tags: codeigniter

I don't know why matches function doesn't run. I want user introduce a password and confirm it introducing it again. The problem is that when I use matches function in order to compare both passwords Codeigniter indicates that passwords are not equal after introducing both equals.

Here is the code:

```
public function validacion_registro() 
{
    $this->input->post('correo');
    $this->input->post('usuario');
    $this->input->post('contrasenya');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('correo','Direcci&oacute;n de correo','trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('usuario','Nombre de usuario','trim|required|min_length[5]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contrasenya','Contrase&ntilde;a','trim|required|md5|xss_clean|matches[repcontrasenya]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('repcontrasenya','Confirmaci&oacute;n de contrase&ntilde;a','trim|required|md5|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('privacidad','Pol&iacute;tica de privacidad','trim|required|md5|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
     {
        redirect('anuncios/test');
        echo ("validaci&oacute;n v&aacute;lida");
     }
    else {
            $this->load->view('anuncios/login');
         }  
}
```

The error is in the comparison between contrasenya and repcontrasenya. When both are equal Codigniter indicates that are different.

Whats wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The command: $this->form_validation->run() returns true if you don't have errors.

Modify the code with:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    redirect('anuncios/test');
    echo ("validaci&oacute;n v&aacute;lida");
}
else 
{
    $this->load->view('anuncios/login');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this is not the problem.

Comment: Now it works. It was the order of rules. Instead of $this->form_validation->set_rules('contrasenya','Contrase&ntilde;a','trim|required|md5|xss_clean|matches[repcontrasenya]');

Comment: I typed matches after required rule. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Got same error, anyway to fix? I even changed the order :(